# Is it allowed / possible to OR two opamp-outputs?

Tags: operational-amplifier, logic-gates

See schematic.

As from what I have been able to read, coupling two outputs together is a Very Bad Idea. I yet lack the knowledge to understand why, though.

But; if one adds a diode in serial with each opamp-output, would it be possible for them to act like an OR-gate (so to speak), controlling the NPN-base? That is, if either U1 or U2 (or both) has a high output, and R1 is chosen properly, will the NPN-base be turned on here?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you're treating the op amp output as a digital signal?

Comment: No other reason than I'm playing around to learn, trying to grasp how opamps works.

Comment: They're analog devices. You don't "AND" or "OR" them, you "sum" or "difference" them.

Comment: This is actually implementing a MAX function, as the voltage at the junction of the diodes will be the higher of the two op amp outputs (less any forward voltage across the diode).

Comment: .elbissopmi ton hguoht ,daer ot reisae hcuM. thgir ot tfel scitamehcs ward yllareneg eW

Comment: Basically, you're using the op-amps as voltage comparators (i.e. open loop, output '1' whenever + input is the highest and '0' otherwise), is that correct? If so, it'd be better to edit the question to precise that. And, yes it is allowed. Is there any reason you'd think it's not ?

Comment: Connecting them together is bad... since you can create a basic rail to rail short, but you are not doing that, you are connecting them through another element, Diodes, so you are fine.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  This could be an analog `max` function.  The output would [still] be analog.  `max` or `min` of two opamps has it's uses: in [Constant Current Constant Voltage power supplies, for example](http://powersupply.blogs.keysight.com/2012/07/how-does-power-supply-regulate-its.html).

Comment: Fair enough. I was trying to make a point more about the types of operations performed rather than enumerate every possible one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, what you show should work.

However, consider the stability of the opamps.  If they are being run open loop (used as comparators) or the feedback path is before the diodes, then it should be OK.  If the diodes are in the feedback path, then things could get unstable.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm playing around to learn, trying to grasp how opamps works

As an aside from the specific circuit in the question.....

You are using the op-amps like comparators and if you looked into a lot of comparators they have open collector outputs that can be wired together to form things like window detectors: -

[image]

If either output transistor is activated it will pull RL down to ground (0 volts) and therefore you have implemented a logic function without the need for diodes.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are not (usually) supposed to connect two outputs together is that outputs are generally low impedance, and they are generally intended to drive relatively high impedances.

Typically op-amps have input impedance in the 100s of megohm range, and output impedance in the tens of ohms. Inputs therefore allow only tiny currents to flow from (or to) outputs.

If you connect two outputs together you are connecting each to the output of the other. Each output will therefore be working into a much lower impedance than it's designed to drive. This may result in excess current, particularly if one output is going high while the other is going low, resulting in voltage sag (i.e. "clipping" of the analog waveform) and possibly even damage to one or the other.

The diodes you have proposed will solve this problem, assuming that the resulting outputs are what you want. For continuous (i.e. analog) signals, resistor-summing can be used to limit the current to safe values, at some cost in signal level.

A good example here may be drawn from common practice in audio work. Line-level output impedance of just about everything is generally from 100 to 600 ohms, while input impedances are usually 10K or more, and use of "wye" adapters to mix outputs together is a bad idea. (Using a "wye" to send one output to two or so inputs, though, is just fine.)

Similarly: power amplifier output impedance is usually a fraction of an ohm, while speakers are usually 4 or 8 ohms, and you *do not ever* connect two power amp outputs in parallel to the same speaker (unless someone else is paying for the repairs, and you are getting kickbacks from the amp repair shop).

For further discussion of this principle, including the use of resistors to "sum" analog signals, see the excellent article "[Why not Wye?](http://www.rane.com/note109.html)" at [Rane Audio](http://www.rane.com/). n.b.: unlike in video and higher-frequency stuff, in audio we don't "match impedance" from source through cable to load.  The wavelengths are much too long and the cables much too short to have to worry about signal reflections.

Comment: Good answer. I'd add **1.** wye cables have actually multiple issues and can be problematic _even_ when used the correct, splitting way, especially in unbalanced connections, due to lack of Galvanic separation. **2.** resistor summing, despite the name, is not summing but _averaging_ if we're talking the typical LF e.g. audio setting where, as you say, outputs have generally much lower impedance than inputs. **3.** Actually, impedances _are_ matched even here, just much more roughly. Reflections are not the only reason to keep impedances at least in the same ballpark, it's also about noise.

Answer (score 1):

I think without diodes it would not be good practice because Opamps are meant to be having very low output impedance. So therfore coupling 2 stages could result in high current flowing between the 2 Opamps which result in lose of power. But with diode it prevents this possibility as D2/D1 will be reverse biased when U1/U2's Output is high respectively.

Looking at the circuit that you have shown , yes it would be possible to have an OR function with this configuration. But it would be important to choose proper R1 values to have the right bias current. Also the same when implemented with MOSFET will result in a more efficient operation (because the gate of a MOSFET is high impedance (could be considered as open) whereas that of BJT is not).